# Python App on Apache2 access via domain

Tags: python, ubuntu, apache2

I am running a python app on port 8080 in a subdirectory on my apache2 webspace on my ubuntu server. I can access this application via server ip and port 8080. I got a domain which refers to my website. I want to access this python app via domain/subdirectory. How can i do this?

Comment: Unless there's something I really don't understand, don't you nust need to point the domain name at the ip?

Comment: no the domain points to my webpage and the app lies in a subdirectory. When i run it i can only access it by using the ip and port and not the domain/subdomain.

Comment: So this is just a regular python file? It's not a django project or anything?

Comment: Yes regular app just using flask.

Comment: i think it has something to do with the apache2 config but im not into it

Comment: Sorry not familiar enough with flask, but i'd be surprised if it was easy/feasible to just plug it into a regular website.